# Return Promise from activate() when customElements have loaded

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, aurelia

I know that Aurelia allows us to return a `Promise()` from the VM's `activate()` method, and if so it'll wait for the promise to resolve before switching to the new view.

But, say I have a view that consists of one or several child components and they all make HTTP requests, how can I know when all children are finished from within my parent component?

Bonus question: Is it correct that only VM's that go in the `<router-outlet>` utilize the `activate()` method, whereas VM's that are used as custom elements utilize the `attached()` method?

Edit: To elaborate a little, here's what one of my pages/routes/main views might look like:

```
<template>
    <main>

        <section id="item">

            <h1>${item.title}</h1>

            <img src="${item.image}">

            <p>${item.description}</p>

            <ul>
                <li repeat.for="si of item.subItems">
                    ${si.subItem}
                </li>
            </ul>

        </section>

        <aside>

            <author-info></author-info>
            <recent-items limit="3"></recent-items>
            <random-quote></random-quote>

        </aside>

    </main>
</template>
```

I can easily wait for `${item}` to load and then resolve the promise in the main view's `activate` method, but that doesn't guarantee that the three child elements in the `aside` have loaded. This makes them pop up one after the other and it doesn't look great.

I'd very much like to use Aurelia's built in functionality if at all possible, but I guess I might have to resort to my own loader using the EventAggregator or a two-way binding like Ashley suggested.

Would love to hear from someone on the Aurelia team as to whether this is possible at all?

Comment: I think I would caution you to reconsider if you want to tie your parent component so tightly to the child components? The answer may be yes or no, but it should be given some careful thought.

Comment: That sounds like sound advice. But in this case the parent component does _nothing_ but include child components. In fact, the `.js` file is empty as of right now and the `.html` file does nothing but `<custom-element-1></custom-element-1><custom-element-2></custom-element-2>` etc so I'm not sure it's that much worse that the JS file also knows about the child components?

Comment: Maybe the data would be better suited flowing in to the custom elements via binding rather than the elements loading it themselves? It's worth considering. I consider what you're asking to be a code smell that would make me step back and reevaluate what I'm doing before proceeding.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps you're right about that :/ The thing is that many of my custom elements should be re-used in several places. Take for example a "Recent Comments"-component that is used on several pages, but in different places, and sometimes with a different number of comments. I'd like to have just one `<recent-comments>` that I can pass arguments to (`limit`, `title`, whatever). This is the child-component I would like to load _before_ Aurelia navigates to the page containing the child component. Now imagine I have _several_ such components.

Comment: I wouldn't want every single page using the `<recent-comments>` element to have to first use the `CommentService` to fetch the most recent comments - I think that's perfectly suited for the `RecentComments` component. Otherwise I'd just have to copy/paste the `CommentService`-code into every single page that uses that element.

Comment: @AshleyGrant any comment on that? I'd love the hear your thoughts. But seems to me like my use case is pretty common. It's rare in my app that a view only consists of one single thing. Most of the time it has its own data, but also includes several custom elements in the sidebar or elsewhere that also fetch data from the server. These are the elements I'd like loaded _before_ displaying my view.

Comment: Would something like this work: https://gist.run/?id=902ba1c51c48094fbe35f1dc298c9838

Comment: Hmm, not sure... because that just prevents the main view from showing up until the other elements have loaded. What I'd prefer is to not even switch to that route until all elements in the route have loaded. Exactly as if the whole route was handled by one view and I returned a Promise from activate. I guess this isn't doable then... I really like the idea of returning a Promise from activate, but it seems very limiting to me that it only allows for one view per route.

Comment: The `<recent-comments>` element seems to depend strongly on the page in which it is loaded. This looks like a blog, and so the comments would be specific to the blog article. Therefore, having them strongly tied to the parent, as Ashley suggested above, and pushing them to the custom elements via binding, is a good strategy and a best practice.

Comment: If you truly want to keep them decoupled, I recommend keeping them truly decoupled, and loading the page independently of the comments, so that the page may show even if the comments are not yet loaded.

Comment: Actually, the `<recent-comments>` just displays the X most recent comments. Not tied to anything else. Also, in truth it was just an example. In my app I have different components. I still don't like how they all pop up one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about such a complex chain with `activate` and `attached`, but you can always use Custom Events.

In `activate` of parent element:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  var subscription = this.eventAggregator.subscribe('child-element-loaded', e => {
    subscription.dispose();
    resolve();
  });
});
```

And in the custom element you'll need to trigger this event whenever needed:

```
this.eventAggregator.publish('child-element-loaded');
```

And, of course, you'll need to import Event Aggregator

```
import {EventAggregator} from 'aurelia-event-aggregator';
```

And inject it into both child and parent elements.

Comment: Thanks for this. I suspected I would have to use the EA. I'll give you the answer unless someone shows me an "official" way to solve the problem. By official I mean perhaps there's a way to access all child elements from within the parent and check whether their attached methods have resolved if you know what I mean? This seems like a common use case, or?

Comment: @powerbuoy well, yes, the CustomEvents thing looks like a hack (because it is one), but it's something concrete that would work under any circumstances ;)

Comment: @AlexanderM.why do you consider the CustomEvents solution to be a hack?

Comment: @AshleyGrant It just appears to me as one, and if it isn't - even better, then my answer wasn't hack-ish :)

Comment: I tried with events today, and unfortunately I don't think it's going to work. The reason being that when the parent returns a promise from its activate method Aurelia won't even run the view (which is expected I suppose), which in turn means the children will never run, which means their events will never fire, which means the parent's promise will never resolve. It's a bit of a catch 22 :/

Comment: @powerbuoy what about just showing blank screen (some overlay, opacity or whatever)?

Comment: Hmm I guess I could do that, yea... Feels like a bit of a hack though especially when Aurelia has this built in.

Comment: I'll keep the question open a while longer, but I might just have to do just that and if so I'll give you the answer.

Comment: I ended up using the EA after all, and the way I do it is I simply trigger a "main:loading" event whenever a custom element that takes up most of the page is loading, I then listen to the event in `app.js` and toggle a `.main-loading` class on `<html>` then use that class to display a spinner and hide unloaded content. This works fine even though it's a little bit of a hassle to remember to trigger the event in every "main" custom element.

Comment: Also, there's no way several custom elements can load at the same time with the current solution. As soon as one publishes `main:loading = false` the spinner will disappear. I guess this could be solved though perhaps by keeping track of the number of `main:loading = true` and only remove the class once as many `main:loading = false` have fired.

Answer (score 6):

### Load all the data in the route's `activate()` callback

As Ashley noted in the comment above, the best strategy is to load all of the data in the parent route and push that data into a custom element via bindings. You mentioned that this would lead to copy/pasted code in each route that contained that element, but we can solve this problem by moving the loading code to a service class and injecting that class into the route. This way, we can keep the code dry while also keep it straightforward and readable.

We'll demonstrate by creating a `<random-quote>` custom element *along with* a service that will provide us with random quotes.

**randomQuoteCustomElement.ts**

```
export class RandomQuoteCustomElement {
    @bindable quote: IQuote;
}
```

**randomQuoteCustomElement.html**

```
<template>
  <i>${quote.text}</i>
  <strong>${quote.author}</strong>
</template>
```

**randomQuoteService.ts**

```
export class RandomQuoteService {

  getRandomQuote: Promise<IQuote>() {
    return this.http.fetch('api/quote/random')
      .then((response) => response.json()) 
    });
  }
}
```

Next, we'll include the custom element in our view, inject the service into our view model, fetch the data through the service, and have our `activate()` method depend on the returned promise.

**main.ts**

```
import { RandomQuoteService} from './randomQuoteService';

@inject(RandomQuoteService)
export class MainViewModel {

  quote: IQuote;

  constructor(quotes: RandomQuoteService) {
    this.quotes = quotes;
  }

  activate() {
    return Promise.all([
      this.quotes.getRandomQuote()
        .then((quote) => this.quote = quote)
    ]);
  }
}
```

**main.html**

```
<template>
  <require from="./randomQuoteCustomElement"></require>
  <random-quote quote.bind="quote"></random-quote>
</template>
```

Because we want our `activate()` function to depend strongly on the results of the `RandomQuoteService`, we need to include this code directly in our `activate()` callback. We can also design the the custom element to *allow* binding data, but fall back to fetching its own data, leveraging the same service.

**randomQuoteCustomElement.ts**

```
export class RandomQuoteCustomElement {

  @bindable quote;

  constructor(quotes) {
    if (!this.quote) {
      quotes.getRandomQuote()
        .then((quote) => !this.quote && this.quote = quote);
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a working example: https://gist.run/?id=c5570192afe5631355efe6b5da3e44b5

Comment: Thanks for this. But honestly I'm still not a fan. I find this much more verbose than I'd like. If I include my random quote component I want it to handle everything. I do keep most of my logic in services already and agree that that makes it easy to fetch anything from anywhere. But imo this is even tighter coupling than what Ashley warned me about. Ideally I'd love something like this.childElements.loaded().then... (I'm typing on my phone so sorry for any typos etc

Comment: okay, I hear you. In fact, `this.childElements.loaded()` does sort of exist. But not all--in fact not most--custom elements are going to be making http calls, so the `loaded()` function actually calls back when the elements are `attached()`, and we could write something that very much does this.

As for verbosity, I would argue that this is actually quite terse. I think what you're having a problem with is that its complex, and I'm with you. However, I just don't think this is a common use case.

Comment: Custom elements are generally designed to replace things like datepickers and dropdowns, which are also elements that get data pushed into them.

Instead of custom elements, have you considered using multiple viewports as detailed here: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/cheat-sheet/7? I didn't suggest this because it implies a tight coupling, but it might better suit your use case.

Comment: Feel free to send me a message on Gitter if you want to discuss design and options further: https://gitter.im/davismj

Comment: Thanks. However, in the skeleton application (and indeed the getting started tutorial) the whole header/navbar of the app is turned into a custom element. I see the benefit of using custom elements for smaller elements too, but don't see why turning `<recent-comments>` into a re-usable "module" is wrong?

Comment: I also noticed the `compose` element recently, but fail to understand how it's different or what it does better than a custom element? If you look at the image in the top of this article https://www.sitepoint.com/composition-aurelia-report-builder/ that's basically what I'm trying to achieve. I have a `page` template and all it does is include the custom elements that make up that particular page.

Comment: `compose` has two compelling use cases. The first is dynamically binding an object to a new view, without instantiating a whole view model for it, which can help keep your views clean and readable. The more important is dynamically binding different views and viewModels, doing something like `<compose view="${obj.type}>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have several http calls that must be returned before rendering the view, you could use `Promise.all`, then bind the results to children components. For instance:

```
activate () {

   let promise1 = new Promise()...;
   let promise2 = new Promise()...;
   let promise3 = new Promise()...;

   return Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]);
   //bind the results to children components
}
```

In this way, `activate()` will await all promises. **However**, as @AshleyGrant said in his comment, you should be careful with this. This could result in a slow process.

Comment: I'm aware of `Promise.all` but not sure how this answers: "say I have a view that consists of one or several child components and they all make HTTP requests, how can I know when all children are finished from within my parent component?".

Comment: Also, I don't think the potential slowness is what Ashley was referring to but rather the tight coupling.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. He was not referring about slowness. I was trying to combine my advice with his but I made a mess with the words :-) (I was working at the time, sorry about that)