# Aurelia event won't fire on first page load

Tags: aurelia

I'm using Aurelia's `EventAggregator` to publish and subscribe to events in my app. Some of my custom elements take a while to load, so I've used a `loading` event to tell my main `app.js` to add a spinner to the page during loading.

This works fine once the app has loaded and I start switching between routes, however, on first page load the event doesn't seem to fire - or at least, it isn't picked up by the `subscribe` method.

Here's basically what my `app.js` does:

```
attached () {
    this.mainLoadingSubscription = this.eventAggregator.subscribe('main:loading', isLoading => {
        // If main is loading
        if (isLoading) {
            document.documentElement.classList.add('main-loading');
        }
        // Stopped loading
        else {
            document.documentElement.classList.remove('main-loading');
        }
    });
}
```

And here's what my custom elements do:

```
constructor () {
    this.eventAggregator.publish('main:loading', true);
}

attached () {
    this.doSomeAsyncAction.then(() => {
        this.eventAggregator.publish('main:loading', false);
    });
}
```

This causes the first page load to *not* show a spinner and instead the page looks kind of broken.

Btw, I am aware of the fact that you can return a `Promise` from the element's `attached` method but I can't do this because of [this other problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38332583/return-promise-from-activate-when-customelements-have-loaded)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Set up your subscriptions in your viewModel's constructor or activate callback

In the above example, you set up subscriptions in the viewModel's `attached()` callback. Unfortunately, this will not be called until all child custom element's `attached()` callbacks are called, which is long after any one custom element's `constructor()` function is called.

Try this:

**app.js**

```
@inject(EventAggregator)
export class AppViewModel {

    constructor(eventAggregator) {
        this.mainLoadingSubscription = eventAggregator.subscribe('main:loading', isLoading => {
            // do your thing
        }
    }
}
```

If the viewModel is a route that can be navigated to, then handle this in the `activate()` callback with appropriate teardown in the `deactivate()` callback.

```
@inject(EventAggregator)
export class AppViewModel {

    constructor(eventAggregator) {
        this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    }

    activate() {
        this.mainLoadingSubscription = this.eventAggregator.subscribe('main:loading', isLoading => {
            // do your thing
        }
    }

    deactivate() {
        this.mainLoadingSubscription.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh this sounds very promising! Will give it a go asap and come back.

Comment: Hm, one thing with this, `constructor()` is only called once per session, whereas `activate()` and `deactivate()` are called every time the view is rendered. This causes the event to be `disposed()` after the view has been.. viewed once.

Comment: Or is that incorrect? Is `constructor` called every time the element is attached? I noticed this behaviour yesterday but can't reproduce now.

Comment: constructor is called every time the element is attached. activate() and deactivate() are called only on navigate to and navigate away respectively. Did you try my solution? Did it not work? If the answer is good, please upvote. If it answers your question, please accept.